# Find and replace with regex in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to remove lines that indicate page numbers from my document.

Rather than go through and manually remove each line, I wanted to do a find/replace with regex.

An example of an offending line is

> Page 62

I'm not having much luck with the regex.

My regex is as follows

```
^Page [0-100]$
```

Scrolling to the bottom of the page, I can see that these lines end at `Page 62` as per above, but this regex isn't finding any results.

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

**EDIT**

I've just tried matching `^Page \d$` also with no results...

Comment: Are you aware what `^` and `$` means? Does the meaning apply to those lines?

Answer (score 1):

`[0-100]` is actually `0-1`, `0`, and `0`, not `0-100`. Therefore it will only match `0` or `1`.

Try this regex:

```
^Page ([0-9][0-9])|(100)$
```

It will match `Page`, then two digits or `100`.

If you don't care how big the page numbers can be, just use the "digit" escape sequence:

```
^Page \d+$
```

Comment: Still no luck :/ normal if I want to replace /r/n, all I type into the search box is `/r/n` but that's using Notepad++'s Extended search, not the regex

Comment: found it thanks to http://blog.creativeitp.com/posts-and-articles/editors/understanding-regex-with-notepad/ :)

Answer (score 1):

You could

```
^Page \d+\s*$
```

Page followed by 1 or more digit followed by any whitespace

Answer (score 1):

Your regex isn't valid. You can't match a number range that way. You have to check each digit.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
^Page [[:digit:]]+$
```