# how do i find and replace different numbers in multiple otherwise identical lines? (notepad++)

Tags: notepad++

three examples:

> SoundVolume = 40
>
> SoundVolume = 140
>
> SoundVolume = 9

the digits range from 1-140, I want to find every line that starts with SoundVolume and to simply replace any number after the equals in such lines with a single number. So, the three lines I posted above become this:

> SoundVolume         = 144
>
> SoundVolume         = 144
>
> SoundVolume         = 144

any help is much appreciated

Comment: Find: `SoundVolume = \K\d+` Replace: `144`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find and replace with regex in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358431/find-and-replace-with-regex-in-notepad)

Answer (score 0):

In NotePad++ search for `SoundVolume =`  so that F3 would bring the next one. Then start record a macro that does F3 then jump to end of line then back select one word, then type 144 then stop recording. Now you can play this macro to the end of file.